# Not sure of my approach for a specific part in React Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a mini React Redux app, where initially I am loading a list of articles. Clicking on each of these articles should render that specific articles content and details on the page.

My current app architecture is as following

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <AppHeader></AppHeader>
                <PageContent></PageContent>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**PageContentContainer.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.simpleReducer.posts
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {

    return {
        frontPagePosts: () => {
            dispatch(actions.frontPageItems())
        }
    }
};


class PageContentContainer extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.frontPagePosts();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <main>
                    <FrontPageComponent posts={this.props.posts}/>
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The **FrontPageComponent** is just a view rendering component with no logic in it.

```
class FrontPageComponent extends Component{
    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container frontPageContainer">
                    {this.props.posts.map((val, idx) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={idx} className='row frontPageContent'>
                                <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <h2>
                                        <a href={'/' + val.slug}>
                                            {val.title}
                                        </a>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">{val.excerpt}</div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My current thought process is introduce another view component for viewing the individual article `<ReadArticleComponent/>`. Every time a user clicks on the individual article, it would change a boolean state value called `showArticle` in the store. Based on this it would render either components accordingly. So for example the logic in my PageContentContainer would look like

```
componentDidMount(){
    //ajax call to the backend

    if(!this.props.showArticle){
     this.props.frontPagePosts();
    }else{
      this.props.showArticleContent()
    } 
}

.........

render(){
   ......

   {!this.props.showArticle ? <FrontPageComponent.../> 
     : <ReadArticleComponent/>
   }
}
```

But how would I handle the case where the user hits the back button and goes back to the page with all the articles. Is my approach right or should I be using React Router in my app?

Comment: yes, you should be using react-router.

Comment: If your individual artice view looks and behaves like a diferent page you should use React Router.

Comment: You can use react router for a single page app experience...or just render another page entirely. I don't see a problem with loading a separate page.

Comment: if I were to use react router, would that mean I would need two different containers

Comment: Visit [reach router](https://reach.tech/router) or [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) docs to get the details.